# run python script with arguments in another python script

Tags: python

I had a script which converts all csdl (xml) documents into JSON documents.
The script can be run in command line by giving two arguments such as source folder where csdl files are located and output folder destination where all generated JSON files are to be stored.

The Command line used for this script is

```
python3 csdl-to-json.py --input <CSDL-Dir> --output <JSON-Dir>
```

Now I want run this script as part of another python script.

My question is how to run `csdl-to-json.py` script in another script(schema.py) by passing arguments.

Comment: Same way you execute every other executable, unless you know more about the script itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `subprocess.run()`: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["csdl-to-json.py", "--input", "<CSDL-Dir>", "--output", "<JSON-Dir>"])
```

Edited, using the following:

```
subprocess.call(["python3", "/home/sundeep/Desktop/csdl-to-json/script.py", "--input", "/home/sundeep/Desktop/csdl-to-json/metadata", "--output", "/home/sundeep/Desktop/csdl-to-json/json"])
```

Comment: It was giving follwing error:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "schema.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["/home/sundeep/Desktop/csdl-to-json/script.py", "--input" "/home/sundeep/Desktop/csdl-to-json/metadata" "--output" "/home/sundeep/Desktop/csdl-to-json/json"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: Is your `script.py` file executable?

Comment: python3 script.py --input <CSDL-Dir> --output <JSON-Dir>

Comment: Its again giving following error : usage: script.py [-h] --input INPUT --output OUTPUT [--config CONFIG]
                 [--overwrite OVERWRITE]
script.py: error: the following arguments are required: --input/-I, --output/-O

Comment: Thank you...small correction, comma should be there : subprocess.run(["python3", "/home/sundeep/Desktop/csdl-to-json/script.py", "--input", "/home/sundeep/Desktop/csdl-to-json/metadata","--output", "/home/sundeep/Desktop/csdl-to-json/json"])