# Run python script with arguments in another python script with its own arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I implemented what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421958/run-python-script-with-arguments-in-another-python-script) to run a script1.py with arguments in another script2.py with its own arguments but this passes the arguments to the script1.py in the string form. script1.py has arguments of types int, float, bool, etc. So is there a way to pass those arguments to script1.py in their original type not in the string form or I have to convert them all to their respective types in script1.py?

Comment: You must pass them in string form (because effectively they are command-line arguments).

Comment: So I have to convert them to their respective types in script1.py, there is no other way, right?

Comment: If you are going to use `subprocess` and pass them as command-line arguments, then no, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

for this, I would construct a bash command string `cmd` and call it with

```
import os
cmd = "python3 script2.py arg1 arg2 arg3"
os.system(cmd)
```

This is then exactly what you would put into bash - thus, types should be recognized by bash as usually.

Comment: I guess the order of the arguments matters here, it should match the one in script1.py right?

Comment: sure, of course you have to write script2.py in a way that it takes arguments in the order like script1.py does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **argparse**

Example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("square", help="display a square of a given number",
                    type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.square**2)
```

For more details check:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html